# I am learning about dart & flutter and i am facing a issue, can someone suggest How to add an unnamed constructor to the 'Note' class in Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

***This is my full code, i have a dart file note.dart ***

```
class Note {

  int _id;
  String _title;
  String _description;
  String _date;
  int _priority;

  // Note(this._title, this._date, this._priority, this._description);
  Note.withId(this._id, this._title, this._date, this._priority, [this._description = '']);
  // Note.withId(this._id, [this._title = '', this._date = '', this._priority = 0, this._description = '']);

  int get id => _id;

  String get title => _title;

  String get description => _description;

  int get priority => _priority;

  String get date => _date;

  set title(String newTitle) {
    if (newTitle.length <= 255) {
      this._title = newTitle;
    }
  }

  set description(String newDescription) {
    if (newDescription.length <= 255) {
      this._description = newDescription;
    }
  }

  set priority(int newPriority) {
    if (newPriority >= 1 && newPriority <= 2) {
      this._priority = newPriority;
    }
  }

  set date(String newDate) {
    this._date = newDate;
  }

  // Convert a Note object into a Map object
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

    var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (id != null) {
      map['id'] = _id;
    }
    map['title'] = _title;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['priority'] = _priority;
    map['date'] = _date;

    return map;
  }

  // Extract a Note object from a Map object
  Note.fromMapObject(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : _id = map['id'],
        _title = map['title'],
        _date = map['date'],
        _priority = map['priority'],
        _description = map['description'];


}
```

***I am getting the error***

> The class 'Note' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.

***Error on line 47, on this code segment***

```
onPressed: () {
          debugPrint("Floating action button was clicked");
          navigateToDetail(Note('','',2), "add Note");
        },
```

```
void navigateToDetail(Note note, String title) async {

    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return NoteDetail(note, title);
    }));

    if (result == true) {
      updateListView();
    }
  }
```

> How can I resolve the error "The class 'Note' doesn't have an unnamed constructor" in my Dart code? I have a note.dart file with a Note class that has a default constructor with named parameters, but I'm still getting the error. The error occurs on line 47, where I'm trying to pass an instance of the Note class to a function. I have also tried to identify other errors, but I have not been able to find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your unnamed constructor is commented out. Leaving just the `Note.withId` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variables to use unnamed constructors. To do this you need to have final variables.

```
class Note {
  Note(this.id, this.title);

  Note.withId(this.id, this.title);

  final int id;
  final String title;
}
```

Comment: This answer is kind of backwards. `final` and non-nullable variables that aren't `late` must be initiaized by *every* generative constructor.  There is nothing different about unnamed constructors, and the member variables do not need to be `final`.